# How to get gvfs to automount removable devices when not using Unity or Gnome Shell

Tags: 14.04, automount, gvfs

Back in 13.04 I switched from using Unity to using a Gnome session with i3. My setup is a based on [this one](http://blog.hugochinchilla.net/2013/03/using-gnome-3-with-i3-window-manager/).

```
$ cat /usr/share/xsessions/gnome-i3.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GNOME with i3
Comment=A GNOME fallback mode session using i3 as the window manager.
Exec=gnome-session --session=i3
TryExec=gnome-session
Icon=
Type=Application

$ cat /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/i3.session
[GNOME Session]
Name=gnome-i3
RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;i3;
```

Back in 13.04, and also in 13.10, automounting worked just like in Unity. If I plugged in a removable drive (eg: a USB thumb drive) it'd mount at `/media/$USER/$VOLUME_LABEL`.

Under 14.04 this still works if I use Unity, but it no longer works in my preferred Gnome+i3 session.

If I start up nautilus (in a Gnome+i3 session) after plugging in a drive I can see the not-mounted drive in the left pane, but it has no eject button. It also does not show up in the output of `df`. If I then click on the drive, an eject button appears, and it will also appear in the output of `df`. So it seems that nautilus mounts volumes "on demand".

I've also found that I can run `gvfs-mount -oi` to see gvfs events as they happen, and when a drive is attached it generates a pair of events like this:

```
Drive connected:    'Lexar USB Flash Drive'
  Drive(0): Lexar USB Flash Drive
    Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
    ids:
     unix-device: '/dev/sdg'
...

Volume added:       'ALLMYDATAZ'
  Volume(0): ALLMYDATAZ
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
    ids:
     class: 'device'
     unix-device: '/dev/sdg1'
     uuid: 'BE64-1766'
     label: 'ALLMYDATAZ'
    themed icons:  ...
    symbolic themed icons:  ...
    can_mount=1
    can_eject=1
    should_automount=1
    sort_key=gvfs.time_detected_usec.1404417627659873
```

(Note the `should_automount=1` bit, yet it still does not automount.)

I can then manually mount the drive with `gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdg1`.

So... is there some pre-existing tool that ties these together, mounting the `unix-device` of all "Volume added" events that have `should_automount=1`? That is, mounting removable volumes as they are added to the system?

Note that I am *not* looking for a way to have things mount at login or at system startup. I want them to mount when plugged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question didn't get any answers I went ahead and wrote [gvfs-automount](https://github.com/xenomachina/gvfs-automount).

When running it will listen for "volume-added" events, and if the added volume has "should_automount" set, mounts it. It also generates a desktop notification when a volume is mounted.